# Increase width and height of popup.html chrome extension css

Tags: css, google-chrome-extension

How can I increase the width and height of my chrome extension's popup.html with css? The only thing that I have on the popup.html is text and a div. CSS just sets the size of a div. I would like the popup.html to be different sizes depending on the screen size. I would prefer that I don't have to use media queries, but if that is the only way to do it, than media queries are fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the CSS for the `<body>`, for example:

```
body {
   width:400px;
   height:300px;
}
```

Comment: Can I do the same thing with percentages? px works, but I want chromebook users not to think the popup is really big, and desktop users to think it is small.

Comment: Percentages don't work well with `<body>`, but you can try [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) for different screen sizes. Never tried those for extensions popups, but they might work.